# How to receive SSH public keys?

Tags: ssh, sshd, authentication

I'm starting to administer a new Mac Mini as a server for my office. We would like to be able to SSH into the machine but do not want password authentication enabled long-term, favoring strong public key auth.

`ssh-copy-id` still requires a password to operate, at least the first time. Is it possible to disable password authentication on a per-account basis if a public key is associated with the account?

Alternatively, is there an automated (as in: I don't have to check my email) way to install those public keys that doesn't involve a user-set password, uses a one-time password, etc.?

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is about. For __a)__, you really can enable/disable password auth on a per-user basis in `sshd_config`. Is your Q about that? For __b)__ you don't need the `ssh-copy-id` script; you can just append the public key to the user's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` by other means.

Comment: Also, `sshd_config` offers different ways to manage the authorized keys centrally instead of via `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` files inside each users home dir.

Comment: Any automated method is going to open a huge can of security worms.   You could do it from procmail, but you'd want to verify that the key was really sent by the user (e.g. require the user to have a **known** gpg key to send a signed email, for procmail rule to verify the signature - shifting the keys problem from ssh to gpg).  Or you could set up a web app system for users to log in and upload a key. but then you'd have to hope that your web app didn't have any exploitable holes (and remember, some of it would have to run as root in order to install authorized_keys in the users' home dirs)

Comment: in short, for a single server in a single office, the most viable/practical answer is **make the users install their keys** (and accept that you'll probably still have to do some manually.  bosses in particular are resistant to doing stuff they don't see as being important).   The time and effort required to build, test, secure (hah! :-), and maintain a custom automated system for this vastly exceeds the time and effort in making the users do it and doing some manually when you have to.

Comment: @cas - well, sure. But if a ready-made solution were available and all I had to do was install it...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a config-management-system such as [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) or [Puppet](https://puppet.com/).

Having used both, I think Ansible is easier to learn for an Ops-Guy.
The [authorized_key](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/authorized_key_module.html?highlight=authorized_key#examples) module is straightforward to use.

Comment: You don't use either ansible or puppet to manage just one machine.  It would be  overkill for the task, and hours or more of work setting it up.  and even if the OP doesn't care about that, this answer still doesn't provide any **automated** way for the OP to get the keys from the users.   They'd still have to manually enter them into the ansible or puppet config, which is not much different than manually editing/creating `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` for each user.

Answer (score 0):

You asked "*Is it possible to disable password authentication on a per-account basis if a public key is associated with the account?*"

Unfortunately, `sshd_config` doesn't have any option to do that.  Maybe you could submit a wishlist bug report asking for the feature (but first check whether the "bug" has been submitted before).   Don't expect a positive - or quick - response.

In the meantime, you could announce a cut-off date sometime in the future (at least a month) when password authentication will be disabled, and that users will need to install a public key before then.

Put the same message in `/etc/motd` too, so they get reminded every time they log in.   Provide at least a link to a web page with instructions for a) generating a public/private key pair on various common platforms, and b) various methods of installing a public key into `~/.ssh/authorized_kets` on your mac mini server.

If you wanted to do some really evil nagging about it, you could set up a cron job to expire the passwords of every non-system user who doesn't have a `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file, forcing them to change their password every time they log in.   **Not recommended** in anything even resembling a professional environment, but possibly OK for a short time on a home server where the users are slack family/friends.

Comment: Re first sentence, it’s extremely unclear what is the “that” which sshd config doesn’t have an option to do.  It doesn’t help that the question itself lumps several things together, but you exacerbate that by not stating which you are answering.

Comment: the "that" is the OP's question `Is it possible to disable password authentication on a per-account basis if a public key is associated with the account?`

Comment: At least, that's the question I was answering.      OTOH, "sshd doesn't have any option to do that" unintentionally applies equally well to all the questions the OP asked.

Comment: I can think of a somewhat kludgey, hackish, method.  Setup a `match group`, with a groupname designated only for this purpose, and put in the required `AuthenticationMethods` directive in it.  Then run a cron job (say once every hour) that looks at all user's `~/.ssh` and if an `authorized_keys` file is present, adds that user to the group using `usermod` or something.  Reduce or increase that 1 hour time to suit your level of paranoia.

Comment: @sitaram, yep. that would make a good answer for you to write up, but reversed. the group should start with all users in it, and sshd configured to allow password auth for that group.  sshd's default auth method should be pubkey only.  The cron job removes users from the group if they have an authorized_keys file (and optionally after an announced cut-off date).    Users would still have to install their own key.